SQL Server deadlock select/delete
How can I solve select and delete deadlock problems in my project?
Deadlock in 2 SQL queries:
(@pr0 int)delete from [table] where [column1] = @pr0

(@pr0 int)select [column1], [column2], [column3], [column4], [column5] from [table] where [column2] = @pr0

I exported deadlock reports. but I still didn't find the problem.
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/dnfGzbph7p/
Build deadlock graph:
enter image description here

Possibly you can use NOLOCK hint on your select statement (but have to be careful this selects data that is not fully committed) so it may not work for your situation but if it does, it would stop the deadlock on selects.  Dig into what NOLOCK does to see if it will be ok to turn on for your situation.

this might be worth reading

Why are you not using READ COMMITTED SNAPSHOT? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/snapshot-isolation-in-sql-server

@Brad, NOLOCK can cause duplicate or missing rows in the results, not just uncommitted data.

Do you have indexes on column1 and column2 to avoid a full scan and improve concurrency?

@DanGuzman have 2 indexes column1 - primary key clustered, column 2 - NONCLUSTERED index
